# websockets (pusherapp) and backbone when to update view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, pusher

I've included Pusher in my backbone app and I'm wondering what the right way is to deal with updates.
Currently, when a model is modified on the client, a PUT event is sent to the server, server updates DB and fires an updated event that is being picked up by Pusher on the client.

My question: Should I update the view immediately on the client (to keep snappy-nes) and just do nothing on the Pusher event on the initiating client or should I update my view in the 'update event' from Pusher?

Note: My original implementation was to update the view in an change event of the model on the client.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but it sounds like you should update the model when the Pusher event is received. The view should then update via the standard backbone mechanism. I'd keep the view and Pusher decoupled.

Comment: I will update the model accordingly on all connections when the Pusher event is received but I'm wondering what to do on the client that initiates the update, ignore the pusher event since the backbone model is already updated?

Comment: so you're trying to avoid getting two events 1. from the client update 2. from the Pusher update? If that's the case you should have a look at http://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/server_excluding_recipients

Comment: @leggetter Yeah that's great, didn't find that info before. thanks!